# Why does Wordpress redirect when I separate wp-core and wp-content?

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite, svn

I'm trying to setup my Wordpress projects so that I can have `http://www.example.com/` as my site URL, say mapped to `/var/www/vhosts/www.example.com/` and in there, I would like to use the following structure:

```
/var/www/vhosts/www.example.com/wp-core/
/var/www/vhosts/www.example.com/wp-content/
/var/www/vhosts/www.example.com/wp-config.php
```

I would like `wp-core/` to contain the Wordpress core installation as an `svn:external` and with `wp-content` and `wp-config.php` stored in my SVN repo, containing themes, config, etc. for each site.

The following article appears to explain how to go about setting the above structure up:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_With_Clean_Subversion_Repositories

However, I'm hitting an issue where the site loads up correctly, reads it's config from the `wp-config.php` file above `wp-core` as intended, however when I attempt to log in, Wordpress redirects the request from `http://www.example.com/wp-login.php` to `http://www.example.com/wp-login.php/` - note the trailing slash.

Here's a confirmation of the extra lines in `wp-config.php` I've added for this:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/wp-content' );
```

Here's the relevant rows from `wp_options` in my DB:

```
SELECT option_name,option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'home';
home,http://www.example.com

SELECT option_name,option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'site url';
siteurl,http://www.example.com
```

Here's my .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Hey-ho let's go!
    RewriteEngine On
    # Base is the URL path of the home directory
    RewriteBase /
    # Base goes to WordPress
    RewriteRule ^$ /wp-core/index.php [L]
    # Skip real files and directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # Otherwise send it to WordPress
    RewriteRule .* /wp-core/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Tracing this in Chrome, I can see that a `HTTP 301` from the correct address to the address with the trailing slash is returned by the server, so it would point to the `.htaccess` above, however the first line of the following excerpt contradicts this somewhat:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2014:21:02:59 +0000] [www.example.com/sid#7ffb79860180][rid#7ffb7b8020a0/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /wp-login.php/
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2014:21:02:59 +0000] [www.example.com/sid#7ffb79860180][rid#7ffb7b8020a0/initial] (1) pass through /wp-login.php/
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2014:21:02:59 +0000] [www.example.com/sid#7ffb79860180][rid#7ffb7b8020a0/initial] (3) [perdir /Users/joe/tmp/example.com/trunk-new/] add path info postfix: /Users/joe/tmp/example.com/trunk-new/wp-login.php -> /Users/joe/tmp/example.com/trunk-new/wp-login.php/
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2014:21:02:59 +0000] [www.example.com/sid#7ffb79860180][rid#7ffb7b8020a0/initial] (3) [perdir /Users/joe/tmp/example.com/trunk-new/] strip per-dir prefix: /Users/joe/tmp/example.com/trunk-new/wp-login.php/ -> wp-login.php/
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2014:21:02:59 +0000] [www.example.com/sid#7ffb79860180][rid#7ffb7b8020a0/initial] (3) [perdir /Users/joe/tmp/example.com/trunk-new/] applying pattern '^$' to uri 'wp-login.php/'
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2014:21:02:59 +0000] [www.example.com/sid#7ffb79860180][rid#7ffb7b8020a0/initial] (3) [perdir /Users/joe/tmp/example.com/trunk-new/] add path info postfix: /Users/joe/tmp/example.com/trunk-new/wp-login.php -> /Users/joe/tmp/example.com/trunk-new/wp-login.php/
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2014:21:02:59 +0000] [www.example.com/sid#7ffb79860180][rid#7ffb7b8020a0/initial] (3) [perdir /Users/joe/tmp/example.com/trunk-new/] strip per-dir prefix: /Users/joe/tmp/example.com/trunk-new/wp-login.php/ -> wp-login.php/
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2014:21:02:59 +0000] [www.example.com/sid#7ffb79860180][rid#7ffb7b8020a0/initial] (3) [perdir /Users/joe/tmp/example.com/trunk-new/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'wp-login.php/'
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2014:21:02:59 +0000] [www.example.com/sid#7ffb79860180][rid#7ffb7b8020a0/initial] (2) [perdir /Users/joe/tmp/example.com/trunk-new/] rewrite 'wp-login.php/' -> '/wp-core/index.php'
```

Specifically: `requested uri /wp-login.php/` indicates that Apache receives a request for `/wp-login.php/` and not `wp-login.php` and `mod_rewrite` passes through the request.

Can anyone offer any suggestions on how I can set this up so that I can have WP core files in one directory in the doc root and `wp-config/` alongside the WP core directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By utilising the `.htaccess` file provided in the following link, I was able to access wp-login again, without redirecting to a URL with a trailing slash:

http://ottopress.com/2011/creating-a-wordpress-site-using-svn/

Answer (score 0):

`wp-login.php` is an actual file that is directly loaded up instead of using a rewrite rule. If you look at file listing in `/var/www/vhosts/www.example.com/`, you'll probably will not see the `wp-login.php` file. But if you check `/var/www/vhosts/www.example.com/wp-core/`, you'll probably find it if I understand your configuration correctly. This means your login URL is actually: `http://www.example.com/wp-core/wp-login.php`

Now there is another issue with your current setup. WordPress doesn't know the URL to where the core files and hence the admin area of the site. By default, WordPress uses the same URL for the public side (`home url`) and the installation folder (`site url`). You can [configure this in your `wp-config.php` file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29):

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/wp-core' ); // Where the WP core is
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com/' ); // Where the public goes to view your blog
```

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong, but does the line `RewriteRule ^$ /wp-core/index.php [L]` not resolve the issue you describe of having to include `/wp-core` in the URL by rewriting the URL to the `index.php` file in `/wp-core`?

Comment: No. `/wp-core/index.php` handles the front-end/public facing side of the site for pretty URLs. It does not handle the login or admin pages.

Comment: I understand that, however that was not what I meant, but I should have been clearer.